# mapreduce matrix multiplication with hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run the matrix multiplication example mentioned(with source code) on the following link:

http://www.norstad.org/matrix-multiply/index.html

I have hadoop setup in pseudodistributed mode and I configured it using this tutorial:

http://hadoop-tutorial.blogspot.com/2010/11/running-hadoop-in-pseudo-distributed.html?showComment=1321528406255#c3661776111033973764

When I run my jar file then I get the following error:

```
Identity test
11/11/30 10:37:34 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
11/11/30 10:37:34 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201111291041_0010
11/11/30 10:37:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
11/11/30 10:37:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
11/11/30 10:37:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201111291041_0010
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 17
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=2
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=2
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=114
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=248
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=298
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=124
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=2
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=4
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=60
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=2
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=8
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=100
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=4
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=4
11/11/30 10:37:58 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
11/11/30 10:37:59 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201111291041_0011
11/11/30 10:38:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
11/11/30 10:38:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
11/11/30 10:38:21 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201111291041_0011
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 17
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=1
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=1
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=34
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=124
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=100
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=124
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=2
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=2
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=2
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=0
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=2
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=4
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=24
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=2
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=2
11/11/30 10:38:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=2
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot open filename /tmp/Matrix Multiply/out/_logs
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSClient.ja va:1497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.<init>(DFSClient.java :1488)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:376)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSyst em.java:178)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.openFile(SequenceFile.java:1 437)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:142 4)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:141 7)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:141 2)
        at TestMatrixMultiply.fillMatrix(TestMatrixMultiply.java:62)
        at TestMatrixMultiply.readMatrix(TestMatrixMultiply.java:84)
        at TestMatrixMultiply.checkAnswer(TestMatrixMultiply.java:108)
        at TestMatrixMultiply.runOneTest(TestMatrixMultiply.java:144)
        at TestMatrixMultiply.testIdentity(TestMatrixMultiply.java:156)
        at TestMatrixMultiply.main(TestMatrixMultiply.java:258)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl. java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

Can someone please suggest me that what am I doing wrong?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It trys to read the job output. When you submit this to your cluster it will add this _log directory. Since directory are no sequence files, they can't be read.

You have to change the code that reads this.

I have scripted something equal:

```
FileStatus[] stati = fs.listStatus(output);
for (FileStatus status : stati) {
    if (!status.isDir()) {
        Path path = status.getPath();
        // HERE IS THE READ CODE FROM YOUR EXAMPLE
    }
}
```

http://code.google.com/p/hama-shortest-paths/source/browse/trunk/hama-gsoc/src/de/jungblut/clustering/mapreduce/KMeansClusteringJob.java#127

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I got it right. Do you have any idea, about the matrix multiplication example which I mentioned in question, that why this works fine with hadoop standalone mode but does not work with hadoop distributed mode at the point of checking answers?

Comment: Because when running in distributed mode, the _log is stored in HDFS, where as in pseudo distributed mode/Standalone mode this is going to be stored in the tasktracker log.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a primitive suggestion but, you may need to change log filename with
/tmp/Matrix\ Multiply/out/_logs. Spaces in directory names may not be handled automatically and I assumed you are working on Linux.

Comment: Thanks miette. yes I am using linux and the thing is that all these log files and paths are defined by the program itself.so then do you still think that it might be the same problem you described? As I am quite new to this field so please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in TestMatrixMultiply.java:

1. As Thomas Jungblut said, _logs should be excluded in readMatrix() method. I have changed the code like this:

   ```
   if (fs.isFile(path)) {
           fillMatrix(result, path);
       } else {
           FileStatus[] fileStatusArray = fs.listStatus(path);
           for (FileStatus fileStatus : fileStatusArray) {
               if ( !fileStatus.isDir() )  // this line is added by me
                   fillMatrix(result, fileStatus.getPath());
           }
       }
   ```
2. In the end of main() method, fs.delete should be commented, or the output directory will be immediately deleted each time after a mapreduce job finished.

   ```
   finally {
           //fs.delete(new Path(DATA_DIR_PATH), true);
       }
   ```